# JS function undefined although JS framework attached

Tags: 8, javascript

I attached materialize to my library theme.

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    base:
      materialize/css/materialize.min.css: {}
      css/style.css: {}
  js:
    materialize/js/materialize.min.js: { minified:true}
    js/layout.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/jquery
```

But in layout.js I run .sidenav() and it says it's undefined.

```
  (function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = { 
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.sidenav', context).once('.sidenav').each(function () {
        M.AutoInit();
        $('.sidenav').sidenav();
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

I can't find how to properly call 3rd party js functions in my custom scripts. I'm not sure why if

```
 $('.sidenav', context).once('.sidenav').each...
```

is correct because I don't need to call a function for each. The example Drupal gives is confusing.

Comment: Seems that materialize.min.js didn't got attached. You sure have it in that location?

Comment: Yeah, Dev tools shows its loading right before the layout.js.

Comment: Do you maybe need to call `M.AutoInit();` first? See https://materializecss.com/auto-init.html

Comment: Thanks for your help.Yeah, same issue. Just M is not defined this time. I've tried both with jquery and without jquery materialize functions. It's not connected to materialize even though it's loaded.

Comment: You need to wait until the DOM's ready before playing with it: `$(function() { $('.sidenav').sidenav(); });`. Also have a peek at the [JS docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview), behaviors specifically, which are the "Drupal way" to wait for the DOM

Comment: I've tried that and I still get the same error. I edited the post above to show the new code.

Comment: It's supposed to be called `$('.sidenav', context).once('myModuleBehavior').each...`, not once on the selector. I just tried it out myself, everything worked fine. Though the libs are actually inside `materialize/dist` not just `materialize/js`. The right path for me was `materialize/dist/js/materialize.min.js`.

Comment: Is myModuleBehavior suppose to be defined in the library or elsewhere? I don't understand the connection with that?

Comment: It’s being defined right there

Comment: Thanks, I read more about drupal.behaviors and understand it better now. I can input jquery and vanilla javascript fine but if I try to call functions from materialize, it doesn't work. I redownloaded the framework from their website and it still doesn't work. It shows the file is loading before this custom script but won't access the functions from it.

Answer (score 0):

So Leymannx was right about the dist folder version of Google Materialize. I had downloaded the framework directly from their get started page. I thought it was the same files, everything else worked, even when I just created a simple index.html on my local server, the simple sidenav() worked. For the heck of it and being completely out of ideas, I did a node install of Google's materialize framework and saw the dist folders. So I switched to loading those dist files and it worked this time in Drupal. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Thanks for everybody's help.